# Wrong character in the file by 0xFF - JAVA

Tags: java, binary, converters

I have a function that the binary values are converted to characters, and write these characters to file.

Binary value: 11100111 11111111 11111010 11100111

```
    String input = "11100111111111111111101011100111";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 

    Arrays.stream( 
        input.split("(?<=\\G.{8})") 
    ).forEach(s -> 
        sb.append((char) Integer.parseInt(s, 2)) 
    );

    String output = sb.toString();
```

By the first, third, and the fourth 8 bit the convert is ok, but by the second 8 bit is wrong. The output is -1. I understand why do this, but i don't know how to fix my code for the correct character write to a file.

The problem is: Wrong character in the file.

On my Eclipse output console: çÿúç
In the file: з?ъз

After write to file `FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("c:\\Users\\FileNameToWrite.txt");` i got this in the file `з?ъз`. This is wrong because the ? mark (Hex: 3F, Binary: 0011 1111). I need the right character value of binary value (1111 1111) in the file.

Thank you!

Comment: çÿúç - this is output that I am getting and I checked online that it is correct for your binary string. Is this not what you are expecting?

Comment: What is the output you ware expecting, why, and what did you get instead?

Comment: I got the same output on the console: çÿúç 
After write to file `FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("c:\\Users\\FileNameToWrite.txt");` i got з?ъз. 
This is wrong because the ? (0011 1111) mark is not 1111 1111.

Comment: @Ztrew Edit your question and explain what is the problem with your code.

Comment: Your `FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("c:\\Users\\FileNameToWrite.txt");` doesn't look like valid code since it contains only info about file but not content you want to write, nor encoding you want to use.

Comment: I changed the file writing method: `BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream("c:\\Users\\FileNameToWrite2.txt"), "UTF-16"));` This one is better, i got the right characters in the file, but the hexa values of these caharcters are: 00 E7 00 FF 00 FA 00 E7. What/why is 00?

Comment: UTF-16 uses two 16 bits = 2 bytes for single character. `00` is just leading zeroes since you provided value in range requiring only one byte.

Comment: `String` is not a container for binary data. Use a byte array.